# Swift - Button's action doesn’t get triggered unless long tapped

Tags: ios, uibutton, apple-sign-in

I've added a `Sign in with Apple` button in a `UIScrollView`, the way Apple's documentation suggest;

```
let signInWithAppleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .white)
            
signInWithAppleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginWithApple(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
signInWithAppleButton.cornerRadius = 12
            
scrollView.addSubview(signInWithAppleButton)
```

The thing is, the button only responds to very long presses instead of simple taps. I've tried putting it outside the `UIScrollView` and it worked there!

Here's my `UIScrollView`'s and button's setup;

```
fileprivate func setupScrollViewConstraints() {
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
}

func setupSignInWithAppleButton() -> UIControl? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let signInWithAppleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .white)
        
        signInWithAppleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginWithApple(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        signInWithAppleButton.cornerRadius = 12
        
        scrollView.addSubview(signInWithAppleButton)
        
        signInWithAppleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            signInWithAppleButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accountLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            signInWithAppleButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            signInWithAppleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210),
            signInWithAppleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45)
        ])
        
        return signInWithAppleButton
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Any idea what's breaking it?

**EDIT;** This is my handler;

```
@objc private func loginWithApple(_ sender: Any) {
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

I have put a breakpoint inside it, but it only gets activated if I long press the button! Just a reminder, the button works as expected if I place it inside the controller's view!

Comment: Try setting your scrollview's `delaysContentTouches = false`.

Comment: Tried that, didn’t help

Comment: A minimal implementation of your example (I just had to assume a constraint for your label - centered in scrollview) when running on an iPhone11 / iOS 13.6 does not reproduce the issue. The action is immediately happening after touching the button. Maybe any other views involved in your hierarchy causing the issue? Did you try to visually debug the view?

Comment: I don't think it's an AutoLayout issue, because right below `signInWithAppleButton`, I have 2 more buttons, created from Storyboard and they work just fine! Did you actually created a project? Could you please upload it so I can check it?

Comment: Sure, just created a fresh project (single view app template) and then [did this](https://pastebin.com/q1BSvWR2) in the view controller.

Comment: What the heck? And the button works as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!!! I had added a tap gesture on my scroll view, so I could dismiss the keyboard when tapped! For some reason it only broke the Apple's sign in button touch events!

Comment: So it was problem with your code and you had not shared that in your question. It seems to be not a valid question then. Anyways, hope my answer response helped you to figure it out. So can you award the bounty to yourself ? :-)

Comment: Can confirm this solution. I had the same problem with an .onTapGesture keyboard dismissal. Not sure if there is another workaround to allow us to keep the keyboard dismissal gesture in place. In iOS 15 and up, I understand .focusable() can be used, but that does not help for older versions of iOS...

Answer (score 3):

I tried just to add the signInWithAppleButton to UIScorllview as below :

```
@objc func loginWithApple(_ sender: Any) {
    print("loginWithApple")
}

fileprivate func setupScrollViewConstraints() {
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
}

func setupSignInWithAppleButton() -> UIControl? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let signInWithAppleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .white)

        signInWithAppleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginWithApple(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        signInWithAppleButton.cornerRadius = 12

        scrollView.addSubview(signInWithAppleButton)

        signInWithAppleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            signInWithAppleButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
            signInWithAppleButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            signInWithAppleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210),
            signInWithAppleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45)
        ])

        return signInWithAppleButton
    }

    return nil
 }
```

I didn't face any issue, when the button is tapped, "**loginWithApple**" is printed immediately for me. The button is behaving as any other UIButton. I didn't observe any issue.

What are you doing in loginWithApple? With the minimal code you provided, I anticipate there could be some issue in loginWithApple function that could be delaying what you are expecting.

UPDATE:
Below is the behavior. Note that the button in inside UIScrollView. Also on device there is no delay.

[image]

Comment: I have added same as your code, and I got below error however, I didn't observe any delay **loginWithApple
2020-08-21 12:10:32.943294+0200 numberdice[89163:3776941] [core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.xxx.xxxxxxxx}** . However, I think it is some issue specific to your project or coding which cannot be identified by what you provided here. I don't observe any delay when the button is click.